# Angularjs filter with actual value not partial

Tags: angularjs, filter

I am using angularJs filter for two dependent dropdowns to filter options of second dropdown.

The issue here is angular is filtering partially. It is considering **gold** and **rose gold** as same.  My requirement is angular to consider them as different filtrate.

What I want is to populate options in the second dropdown based on the data on first dropdown.But when first dropdown value is **gold** second dropdown options are poulating for both **rose** and **rose gold**. I want to populate for **gold** only.

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl"><select ng-model="selectedColorCategory"  ng-options="colorset.color for colorset in data |unique:'color'"></select>   <select ng-model="selectedColor"  ng-options="colorset.name for colorset in data | filter:{color:selectedColorCategory.color}"></select></div>
```

JS

```
 var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.directives','ui.filters']);function MyCtrl($scope) {$scope.data=[{color:'gold',name:'name1'},{color:'rose gold',name:'name2'},{color:'cherry gold',name:'name3'},{color:'black',name:'name4'},{color:'gold',name:'name5'},{color:'grey',name:'name6'}];$scope.selectedColorCategory=$scope.data[0];$scope.selectedColor=$scope.selectedColorCategory;}
```

[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vnkmpafv/)

Comment: You're using a very old version of Angular (at least in jsfiddle). You should probably be using 1.5 at least, or preferably 1.6

Comment: changing to filter:{color:selectedColorCategory.color}:true fixed the issue